# How does visibility work for Java nested classes?

Tags: java, visibility

I'm trying to learn what visibility to assign to nested classes, besides what my IDE yells at me that I have to do. This can get arbitrarily complicated, so I need to understand the general rules.

```
public class A {
    private static class B {
        public int foo; // accessible in A?
        private int bar; // accessible in A?
        public static class C { // accessible in A? everywhere?
        }
        private static class D { // accessible in A?
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, modifiers seem to resolve at the "file" level, not at the level of the encapsulating class. Once one thing is private, anything inside it is private.

What's the actual mechanism of this or the technical explanation? Is this documented somewhere or do I just need to read the JLS?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1

Comment: It is limited to the same outer class.  If you add a package local class to the same file, it doesn't enjoy this access to private members.

Comment: @AAA. Did any of the answers below help, or did we miss the point of your question entirely ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the best summaries of access visibility that I've seen is in the [Java Tutorials > Controlling access to members of a class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), but it glosses over some of the key details. The question I think you are asking is answered in § 6.6.1 of the JLS for SE 7: ["Determining Accessibility"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> If ... public ... Otherwise, if ... protected ...  Otherwise, if ... package access ...
>
> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and **access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor**.

If you read that carefully:

1. any access
2. within the body of the top level class
3. to another `private` (not package-private - that's different) member
4. regardless of how deep it is nested
5. is permitted

So: any member inside any depth of private nested classes is accessible *anywhere within the body* of the top level class (including within other nested sibling classes). However a private nested class, and any member within, is not visible to other top level classes.

For example:

```
public class A {
    private static class B {
        public int foo; // accessible in A and P
        private int bar; // accessible in A and P   
        public static void test(){
            P p = new P();
            p.foo = 1; p.bar = 1;
        }
    }
    private static class P {
        public int foo; // accessible in A and B
        private int bar; // accessible in A and B   
        public static void test(){
            B b = new B();
            b.foo = 1; b.bar = 1;
        }
    }
    public static void test(){
        B b = new B();
        b.foo = 1; b.bar = 1;
        P p = new P();
        p.foo = 1; p.bar = 1;       
    }
}
```

*Note:* This isn't "file level" though. Declare another top level class in that file (which could not be `public` - only one of those allowed per file) and it couldn't see those same nested `private` members.

```
class X {
    public static void test() {
        // all of these statements fail ...
        A.B b = new A.B();
        b.foo = 1; b.bar = 1; 
        b.test();
        A.P p = new A.P();
        p.foo = 1; p.bar = 1;  
        p.test();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Accessibility is relative to the access source. First

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access
>   is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
>   class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.

So all members you've declared in `A` or nested within class in `A` are accessible in `A`.

If you're not within `A`, then `private` members of `A` are not accessible. That means `B` is not accessible. Since `foo`, `bar`, `C` and `D` are members of `B`, you need `B` to access them. But since `B` is not accessible, you can't access those either.

```
public class Unrelated {
   {
       B b; // nope
       A.B b; // nope
       A.B.C c; // nope 
   }
}
```

These rules are more or less all defined in [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) of the JLS.